# Error Connection publisher to broker

Tags: raspbian, pi-4

I also have the following error when I want to enter the command: mosquitto_sub -t "topic_name". The error is "Connection error: Connection Refused: not authorized".
I want to connect it to an ESP32 to store all the information and data in Rpi, in a "server". I leave the code from the Arduino IDE below.

```
    #define LIGHT_SENSOR_PIN 36 // ESP32 pin GIOP36 (ADC0)
#define TRIG_PIN 21 // ESP32 pin GIOP23 connected to Ultrasonic Sensor's TRIG pin
#define ECHO_PIN 22 // ESP32 pin GIOP22 connected to Ultrasonic Sensor's ECHO pin
#include <TFT_eSPI.h> // Graphics and font library for ST7735 driver chip
#include <SPI.h>
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <PubSubClient.h>

const char *ssid = "DIGI-02252501";
const char *password = "kyra2001";
const char *ID = "mihairusu11";
const char *TOPIC = "room";

IPAddress broker(192,168,1,2);
WiFiClient wclient;

PubSubClient client(wclient);

// Connect to WiFi network
void setup_wifi() {
  Serial.print("\nConnecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password); // Connect to network
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) { // Wait for connection
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");
  Serial.print("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
}
// Reconnect to client
void reconnect() {
  // Loop until we're reconnected
  while (!client.connected()) {
    Serial.print("Attempting MQTT connection...");
    // Attempt to connect
    if (client.connect(ID)) {
      Serial.println("connected");
      Serial.print("Publishing to: ");
      Serial.println(TOPIC);
      Serial.println('\n');

    } else {
      Serial.println(" try again in 5 seconds");
      // Wait 5 seconds before retrying
      delay(5000);
    }
  }
}
TFT_eSPI tft = TFT_eSPI();  // Invoke library, pins defined in User_Setup.h
#define TFT_GREY 0x5AEB // New colour
float duration_us, distance_cm;
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  tft.init();
  tft.setRotation(1);
  pinMode(TRIG_PIN, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ECHO_PIN, INPUT);
  setup_wifi(); // Connect to network
  client.setServer(broker, 8883);
}

void loop() {
  if (!client.connected())  // Reconnect if connection is lost
  {
    reconnect();
  }
  client.loop();
  tft.fillScreen(TFT_GREY);
  tft.setCursor(5, 0, 1);
  digitalWrite(TRIG_PIN, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWrite(TRIG_PIN, LOW);
  duration_us = pulseIn(ECHO_PIN, HIGH);
  distance_cm = 0.017 * duration_us;
  float analogValue = analogRead(LIGHT_SENSOR_PIN);
  float procent = (100 * analogValue) / 4095;
  if(distance_cm < 10){
    tft.setTextColor(TFT_RED,TFT_BLACK);  tft.setTextSize(2);
    tft.println("Distanta: "); tft.println(distance_cm);
    tft.println("Foarte aproape");
    client.publish(TOPIC,"merge");
    Serial.println((String)TOPIC + " => merge");
  }
  else if (distance_cm < 30) {
    tft.setTextColor(TFT_BLUE,TFT_BLACK);  tft.setTextSize(2);
    tft.println("Distanta: "); tft.println(distance_cm);
    tft.println("Aproape");
    client.publish(TOPIC,"merge2");
    Serial.println((String)TOPIC + " => merge2");
  }
  else if(distance_cm < 60) {
    tft.setTextColor(TFT_GREEN,TFT_BLACK);  tft.setTextSize(2);
    tft.println("Distanta :"); tft.println(distance_cm);
    tft.println("Indepartat");
    client.publish(TOPIC,"merge3");
    Serial.println((String)TOPIC + " => merge3");
  }
  else{
    tft.setTextColor(TFT_WHITE,TFT_BLACK);  tft.setTextSize(2);
    tft.println("Distanta: "); tft.println(distance_cm);
    tft.println("Foarte indepartat");
    client.publish(TOPIC,"merge4");
    Serial.println((String)TOPIC + " => merge4");
  }
  tft.setTextColor(TFT_YELLOW,TFT_BLACK);  tft.setTextSize(2);
  tft.println("Luminiozitate(%)"); tft.println(procent);
  if (analogValue < 40) {
    tft.setTextColor(TFT_WHITE,TFT_BLACK);  tft.setTextSize(2);
    tft.println("Intuneric");
    client.publish(TOPIC,"aprinde");
    Serial.println((String)TOPIC + " => aprinde");
  } else if (analogValue < 800) {
    tft.setTextColor(TFT_WHITE,TFT_BLACK);  tft.setTextSize(2);
    tft.println("Dimineata");
    client.publish(TOPIC,"aprinde2");
    Serial.println((String)TOPIC + " => aprinde2");
  } else if (analogValue < 2000) {
    tft.setTextColor(TFT_WHITE,TFT_BLACK);  tft.setTextSize(2);
    tft.println("Lumina");
    client.publish(TOPIC,"aprinde3");
    Serial.println((String)TOPIC + " => aprinde3");
  } else if (analogValue < 3200) {
    tft.setTextColor(TFT_WHITE,TFT_BLACK);  tft.setTextSize(2);
    tft.println("Luminos");
    client.publish(TOPIC,"aprinde4");
    Serial.println((String)TOPIC + " => aprinde4");
  } else {
    tft.setTextColor(TFT_WHITE,TFT_BLACK);  tft.setTextSize(2);
    tft.println("Foarte luminos");
    client.publish(TOPIC,"aprinde5");
    Serial.println((String)TOPIC + " => aprinde5");
  }
  delay(500);
}
```

Comment: what sort of authentication have you enabled on your MQTT server

Comment: The "not authorized" is a bit strange, but ["connection refused"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/73782/25985) generally means that the port is accessible,  but there is no server listening on it.  This could be because you have the wrong port number or IP address, or that the software you think is running is not running.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, the problem was in the mosquitto config because it was the port set as the one asking for permission.